# Transforming Date in Two-Way Bound Property in Angular 2 App

Tags: javascript, angular, date, typescript, date-pipe

I have a date being displayed in my Angular 2 app that is printing in an undesired format, like this: `2012-04-02T00:00:00.000Z`

What I'd like to do is use Angular's date pipe to transform this data so it prints in a more human-friendly format. Is there a way I can use the date pipe on an input where I'm using two-way binding? In other words, can I use the date pipe on code that looks like this?

```
<input class="app-input" [(ngModel)]="staff.profile.hireDate" placeholder="None"/>
```

I've tried various attempts, but so far have been unable to do make it work. I'm therefore wondering if it's possible.

And, if not, what would be an alternative way I could handle this via plain JS? I'm open to whatever possibility is effective and simplest to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in your component.

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
```

then either add it to the `providers` array in component or in your ngModule.

In your component you inject this in your constructor:

```
constructor(private myDatePipe: DatePipe) {}
```

and modify your variable property:

```
this.staff.profile.hireDate = 
    this.myDatePipe.transform(new Date(this.staff.profile.hireDate));
```

if you want to specify the output, here for example using the `'short'` option:

```
this.staff.profile.hireDate = 
    this.myDatePipe.transform(new Date(this.staff.profile.hireDate), 'short');
```

Comment: This is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. Much appreciated, @AJT_82!

Comment: Great, glad to hear! :) :)